Why is the area under our retaining walls wet when there has been no rain?
Recently, I have noticed moisture accumulating under the relatively new retaining walls in our backyard each morning, as shown in these photos:




I've put drainage pipes and gravel behind the retaining walls, which work well during rainy periods. However, we haven't had any recent rainfall. Additionally, the water table in our area isn't particularly high, as our house is situated on top of a hill. I don't think the neighbors have recently watered their lawn either. That said, the temperature variations over 24 hours have been significant, typically ranging from 5°C to 25°C (41°F to 77°F), while humidity levels have been quite low (around 10-30%).
What could be causing this substantial water accumulation under the retaining walls every morning? Is it possible that this is entirely due to water vapor condensation?

Since humidity is low, and the temperature change is moderate, it seems unlikely to be from condensation.
However, in some desert locations, it can get quite cold at night, allowing the wall to cool, while the much larger heat storage of the ground keeps it warm, with water evaporating, then condensing on the cold surface. Test that by tossing a plastic tarp atop the wall. If the outside of the tarp is wet in the morning, then it is condensation.
Another possibility is that the flow of ground water, though well above the water table, was interrupted by the wall. To test that, dig down perhaps 15 cm (6") at a few spots along the wall. If the ground is quite wet below the surface, then look for a source of ground water, e.g., a neighbor's sprinkler, air conditioner condensate, or a broken pipe.
